# Memory bandwidth theoretical calculation for GPU

Tags: c++, memory, cuda, bandwidth

I am trying to follow a [tutorial by Mark Harris](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/how-implement-performance-metrics-cuda-cc/). When discussing theoretical memory calculation, he provides a formula for calculating it and provides an example for DDR3-type memory. Important is that one has to multiply the calculation by a factor of 2 due to double data rate. I did the same calculation for my card GeForce GT 750M which has GDDR5 memory, memclock 1250 MHz and 128 bit interface:

`BW = 1250e6 * (180 bit) / (8 bit) * 2 * 1e-9 = 40 Gb/s`

However, specs for this card say that the BW is 80 Gb/s so I am missing a factor of 2 somewhere. Is it the difference between GDDR5 and DDR3?

Comment: You have the wrong memory clock rate. GDDR5 should be of the order of 2-5 GHz.